# 2 AUTO INCREMENT COLUMNS in ONE TABLE

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have table named **ITEMS** where there should be 2 auto increment columns.

So the table structure would be:

```
ID   |   ITEM_ID
---------------------------------
1    |   ITEM201521080225-001
2    |   ITEM201521080301-002
3    |   ITEM201521080345-003
```

The **column.ITEM_ID** structure is ITEM*YearDayMonthHourMinute*-*Increment Value*

I managed to Generate the ITEM*YearDayMonthHourMinute* value thru POST(PHP POST/ PHP Generated).

I am using MySQL and PHPMyAdmin at the moment, and I'm seeing errors if I set column.ITEM_ID to `AUTO_INCREMENT`

How can I make column.ITEM_ID to `AUTO_INCREMENT`? Is it Possible?

Comment: Why do you need this (which is basically storing the ID in 2 places)? Just store the `'ITEM201521080225'` in `item`. Wherever you need this, just `concat()` the 2 columns.

Comment: So, on the 21st day of the 8th month (at 02:25?) you have a new product id? What do you need the `ID` field? You have a unique (and probably - reasonably - natural) key? Anyway, you can't have > [1 auto_increment fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642915/mysql-table-with-more-than-one-auto-incremented-coloumn).